# Issue freeing memory that I still need, linked list

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, linked-list, free

So I'm doing this assignment and as part of the rules, anything extra defined in helpers needs to be free'd at the end.
the question is: take a destination empty linked list, take 2 already sorted linked lists, and merge these two into the destination linked list with their already existing addresses, I'm not allowed to define new nodes.
this is what I have

```
void llmrg(struct llist *dest, struct llist *src1, struct llist *src2)
{
    struct llnode *tempdest = dest->front;
    struct llnode *tempsrc;

    while (src1->front != NULL || src2->front != NULL)
    {
        if (src2->front == NULL)
        {
            tempdest->next = src1->front;
            src1->front = NULL;
        }
        else if (src1->front == NULL)
        {
            tempdest->next = src2->front;
            src2->front = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((src2->front == NULL) || (src1->front->item < src2->front->item))
            {
                tempsrc = src1->front->next;
                if (dest->front != NULL)
                {
                    tempdest->next = src1->front;
                    tempdest = tempdest->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    dest->front = src1->front;
                    tempdest = dest->front;
                }
                src1->front->next = NULL;
                src1->front = tempsrc;
            }
            else
            {
                tempsrc = src2->front->next;
                if (dest->front != NULL)
                {
                    tempdest->next = src2->front;
                    tempdest = tempdest->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    dest->front = src2->front;
                    tempdest = dest->front;
                }
                src2->front->next = NULL;
                src2->front = tempsrc;
            }
        }
    }
    free(tempsrc);
    free(tempdest);
}
```

So now my issue is if I don't do the 'free' statements, everything works, but I'm not allowed to do that, but if I free 'tempdest' (free'ing 'tempsrc' doesn't cause an issue), then 1 of the values goes away because it's still stored using tempdest.

So if my lists are (1,3,5) and (2,4,6), result should be (1,2,3,4,5,6), and it works without free'ing,
but with free'ing I get (1,2,3,4,0,6).

Also the data structures are:

```
struct llnode { int item; struct llnode *next; };
struct llist { struct llnode *front; };
```

By freeing, I don't mean the linked lists, those are obviously being used.  I mean the 2 pointers, `tempdest` and `tempsrc`, that I created for the sake of solving this question — those need to be freed.

Can someone please help me somehow free `tempdest` and also keep the value 5?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon and about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) sooner.  You've not shown us the definitions of the structure types.  Why do you need to free anything?  When you merge the two lists, each item in each of the lists should be in the result list, so none of the items should be freed.  If there's some sort of 'list head' structure (there seems to be: you have `struct llist` and `struct llnode` types), the two old list head structures may need to be freed, but that's all.

Comment: What do you mean by "*but I'm not allowed to do that*"?

Comment: the rules of the assignment don't allow us to leave useless memory un-free'd. we have to free any unnecessary variable and pointer

Comment: @melpomene my guess would be that he need to reuse the node of the 2 inptu list in the destination list, and not create new ones

Comment: You're not allowed to free either `tempsrc` or `tempdest` because they are not allocated by your code.  They are merely temporary pointers to items in the list.  If you free either of them, you will break things.  Please get [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) if at all possible and use it.  It will help you see the error of your ways.  By the end, you will need to ensure that `src1->front` is a null pointer, and that `src2->front` is a null pointer.  But that's all.

Comment: Your function doesn't `malloc` anything so I don't understand what you think you need to `free`.

Comment: Jonathan, I already set them to NULL
The problem is I have special cases where either of src1 or src2 is NULL, and the value that turns 0 is literally the last value before those happen.
So 5 is the last value before the first list goes NULL and that's why it turns to 0, because that value is still depending on tempdest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comments,

> Why do you need to free anything? When you merge the two lists, each item in each of the lists should be in the result list, so none of the items should be freed.

Since you have a 'list head' structure (`struct llist`), you have to set the two old list head structures passed into `llmrg()` so they don't point to anything any more.

> You're not 'allowed' to free either `tempsrc` or `tempdest` because they are not allocated by your code. They are merely temporary pointers to items in the list. If you free either of them, you will break things. Please get [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) if at all possible and use it. It will help you see the error of your ways. By the end of the merge function, you need to ensure that `src1->front` is a null pointer, and that `src2->front` is a null pointer. But that's all.  There's still nothing to free.

This is your code adapted into a test harness.  Note that there is no call to `malloc()` anywhere in this code, and hence no need to call `free()` anywhere either.  This is mainly to make the point rather than because you would use non-dynamic memory allocation in genuine code (but you didn't show the list creation code, and doing things this way avoids having to write that, too).

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct llnode { int item; struct llnode *next; };
struct llist { struct llnode *front; };

static
void llmrg(struct llist *dest, struct llist *src1, struct llist *src2)
{
    struct llnode *tempdest = dest->front;
    struct llnode *tempsrc;

    while (src1->front != NULL || src2->front != NULL)
    {
        if (src2->front == NULL)
        {
            tempdest->next = src1->front;
            src1->front = NULL;
        }
        else if (src1->front == NULL)
        {
            tempdest->next = src2->front;
            src2->front = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((src2->front == NULL) || (src1->front->item < src2->front->item))
            {
                tempsrc = src1->front->next;
                if (dest->front != NULL)
                {
                    tempdest->next = src1->front;
                    tempdest = tempdest->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    dest->front = src1->front;
                    tempdest = dest->front;
                }
                src1->front->next = NULL;
                src1->front = tempsrc;
            }
            else
            {
                tempsrc = src2->front->next;
                if (dest->front != NULL)
                {
                    tempdest->next = src2->front;
                    tempdest = tempdest->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    dest->front = src2->front;
                    tempdest = dest->front;
                }
                src2->front->next = NULL;
                src2->front = tempsrc;
            }
        }
    }
    src1->front = NULL;
    src2->front = NULL;
}

static void print_llist(const char *tag, struct llist *list)
{
    printf("%s:", tag);
    struct llnode *node = list->front;
    while (node != 0)
    {
        printf(" %d", node->item);
        node = node->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    struct llnode data[] =
    {
        { 1, &data[1] }, { 3, &data[2] }, { 5, 0 },
        { 2, &data[4] }, { 4, &data[5] }, { 6, 0 }
    };
    struct llist ll1 = { &data[0] };
    struct llist ll2 = { &data[3] };
    struct llist ll3 = { 0 };
    printf("Before:\n");
    print_llist("ll1", &ll1);
    print_llist("ll2", &ll2);
    print_llist("ll3", &ll3);

    llmrg(&ll3, &ll1, &ll2);

    printf("After:\n");
    print_llist("ll1", &ll1);
    print_llist("ll2", &ll2);
    print_llist("ll3", &ll3);

    return 0;
}
```

I added the two assignments at the end of the `llmrg()` function in lieu of your two `free()` calls.  I'm not sure whether they're necessary, but they certainly do the job.  Clearly, if the list structures or node structures were dynamically allocated, then they'd need to be freed, but not in the `llmrg()` code.

Example output:

```
Before:
ll1: 1 3 5
ll2: 2 4 6
ll3:
After:
ll1:
ll2:
ll3: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Note that you can simplify the merge function considerably — 25 fewer lines of code. (It is generally easier to get small functions correct, and keep them correct.  However, using the `struct llnode **dest` is undeniably subtle, albeit effective.)  When the code contains `&(*dest)->next`, this is equivalent to `&((*dest)->next)` — the address of the `next` pointer pointed to by `*dest`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct llnode { int item; struct llnode *next; };
struct llist { struct llnode *front; };

static
void llmrg(struct llist *dst0, struct llist *src1, struct llist *src2)
{
    struct llnode *node1 =  src1->front;
    struct llnode *node2 =  src2->front;
    struct llnode **dest = &dst0->front;

    src1->front = NULL;
    src2->front = NULL;

    while (node1 != NULL && node2 != NULL)
    {
        if (node1->item < node2->item)
        {
            *dest = node1;
            node1 = node1->next;
        }
        else
        {
            *dest = node2;
            node2 = node2->next;
        }
        dest = &(*dest)->next;
    }

    if (node1 != NULL)
        *dest = node1;
    if (node2 != NULL)
        *dest = node2;
}

static void print_llist(const char *tag, struct llist *list)
{
    printf("%s:", tag);
    struct llnode *node = list->front;
    while (node != 0)
    {
        printf(" %d", node->item);
        node = node->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    struct llnode data[] =
    {
        { 2, &data[1] }, { 3, &data[2] }, { 5, 0 },
        { 1, &data[4] }, { 4, &data[5] }, { 6, &data[6] }, { 8, 0 },
    };
    struct llist ll1 = { &data[0] };
    struct llist ll2 = { &data[3] };
    struct llist ll3 = { 0 };

    printf("Before:\n");
    print_llist("ll1", &ll1);
    print_llist("ll2", &ll2);
    print_llist("ll3", &ll3);

    llmrg(&ll3, &ll1, &ll2);

    printf("After:\n");
    print_llist("ll1", &ll1);
    print_llist("ll2", &ll2);
    print_llist("ll3", &ll3);

    return 0;
}
```

The test data is slightly different; it would work on the original just as happily as on this data.

Example output:

```
Before:
ll1: 2 3 5
ll2: 1 4 6 8
ll3:
After:
ll1:
ll2:
ll3: 1 2 3 4 5 6 8
```

Comment: So if I don't free them, no memory leak or anything of that sort will happen?

Comment: There would not be any leak simply because of the `llmrg()` call, no.  You would need a function to release any dynamically allocated lists — and you'd call that when you've finished with the lists, but not until then.  And that's outside the `llmrg()` function. The merge itself doesn't allocate anything or free anything.  The test scenario shown with no dynamic allocation emphasizes the point — if there's nothing allocated with `malloc()`, there's nothing to release with `free()`.  But it is an extreme example!

Comment: Alright then.
I think I'll do what you recommended.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

> I mean the 2 pointers, `tempdest` and `tempsrc`, that I created for the sake of solving this question — those need to be freed.

No, they don't. You don't free pointers, you free memory blocks allocated with `malloc`. Your function doesn't `malloc` any memory, so it has nothing to `free`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to free tempsrc or tempdst. These pointers have not been allocated any memory but rather just point to memory you already had and need (llnodes in your lists). You actually don't need to free anything. Your situation is similar to this:

```
int* someInts = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); // allocates memory for 10 ints

int* tempInt = &someInt[5]; // points to the 5th int someInts, no new memory allocated 

//free(tempInt);
//There is no need to free this as it is just a pointer
//to some memory already "owned" by someInts

free(someInts);
//Freeing this pointer frees all the memory allocated in the first line.
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need more temporary variable to store the pointer to the node node of each input lists you currently are.

[For the lazy](http://pastebin.com/pi0c0UeS)

Comment: Not my down-vote, but … did you compile the code in the Pastebin?  Does your compiler really accept `struct llnode current==NULL;`?  There should only be one `=` in there, and you can't just initialize a structure type with a pointer like that (you'd need `struct llnode current = { 1, NULL };` or something similar).

Comment: From the top of my head, I was bound to make mistake I guess, thanks for pointing them out, and I assume the downvote, will correct the code tough